# How is a place elevated spiritually?

Tags: blessing, geography, kedusha-holiness, israel

Can a place become holier or spiritually elevated?

If yes, what makes a certain place holier or spiritually elevated?

Is it depended upon the people and their actions that are living in it? Can a Holy person or a person in Higher level elevate the place where he was living?

Can a place be blessed and how?

Are there any holy places or blessed places rather than Israel?

Comment: A place can be spiritually elevated to the extent that you are spiritually in the place. So for example, let's say you went to Israel for a beach holiday, I doubt that would meet the definition of having been in the Holy Land.